# Proof by MVT (no calculator)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

So I need to prove that  $$\frac{1}{16} <\sqrt{51} -7< \frac{1}{
14}$$ using the MVT and no calculator but I can't find a function  that would satisfy those outputs ![as for the question of where is the 2 clearly there isn't one that's exactly why I'm stuck]

Comment: That is going to be hard since it is not true with your current inequalities.

Comment: Where is $2$? In the question

Comment: If there was no $2$ dividing $\sqrt{51}-7$ in the source for this question, it was a mistake in the source.

Comment: Without the $2$ it is wrong.  So no wonder you cannot prove it.  $\sqrt{51}-7 \approx 0.14$ which is not less than $1/14$.  It is greater than $1/16$, though.

Answer (score 4):

The facts that $7 = \sqrt{49}$ and $49$ is close to $51$ should suggest using $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$.  There exists $c \in (49,51)$ satisfying $$\frac{\sqrt{51} - 7}{2} = \frac{f(51) - f(49)}{51-49} = f'(c)$$ where
$$f'(c) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{c}} < \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{49}} = \frac 1{14}$$ and
$$f'(c) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{c}} > \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{64}} = \frac 1{16}.$$
Thus
$$\frac 1{16} < \frac{\sqrt{51} - 7}{2} < \frac 1{14}.$$